# Bcrypt decryption fundamental

Tags: hash, bcrypt, salt

What does salt mean in bcrypt hashing?
Can I retrieve plain text from salt and hash?
Is there any online websites or tools to decrypt bcrypt hash correctly?

Thank my dear freind.

Comment: No hashing is not encryption, hashing is a one way operation, you cannot get back the original plain text. Salting is used to prevent rainbow-table attacks. You could have a look at my [tutorial](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about safely storing passwords to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of hashing is creating input => output transform that's hard to reverse.

The point of salting the input is to prevent identical inputs from getting the same output by adding some random portion to input sequence before hashing.

So no, you cannot retrieve plain text from salt and hash (other than brute forcing or exploiting, if any, vulnerability of bcrypt algorithm or it's implementation).